# Hibernate Cannot add or update a child row issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this relationship

```
@OneToOne(orphanRemoval = true, optional = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL},  mappedBy = "publicProcurement", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Getter
@Setter
private Announcement announcement;


@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "public_procurement_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
@Getter
@Setter
private PublicProcurement publicProcurement;
```

And here my foreign key Constraint

```
 <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="public_procurement_id" baseTableName="announcement" constraintName="announcement_public_procurement_ibfk_1" onDelete="RESTRICT" onUpdate="RESTRICT" referencedColumnNames="id" referencedTableName="public_procurement"/>
```

Now  in my service I do this

```
@Override
public void addAnnouncement(final Integer id, final PublicProcurement publicProcurementForm) {
    PublicProcurement publicProcurement = get(id);
    Announcement announcement = publicProcurementForm.getAnnouncement();
    announcement.setApprovedName(userService.getUserName());
    announcement.setPublicProcurement(publicProcurement);
    announcementService.save(announcement);
    publicProcurement.setAnnouncement(announcement);
    save(publicProcurement);
}
```

But when I save announcementService.save(announcement); I receive below exception

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`etendering_test`.`announcement`, CONSTRAINT `announcement_public_procurement_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`public_procurement_id`) REFERENCES `public_procurement` (`id`))
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.get(SQLExceptionMapper.java:132) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.internal.SQLExceptionMapper.throwException(SQLExceptionMapper.java:106) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeQueryEpilog(MySQLStatement.java:266) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.execute(MySQLStatement.java:289) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLStatement.java:317) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(MySQLPreparedStatement.java:150) ~[mariadb-java-client-1.1.2.jar:na]
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:133) ~[hibernate-core-4.2.7.Final.jar:4.2.7.Final]
```

I try everything but I don't know what I´m doing wrong with Hibernate. any idea guys?

Regards.

Comment: Are you doing `addAnnouncement()` inside a transaction? If not, the two `save()` calls will be done independently and for the split-second between them, the foreign key will be violated.

Comment: yes it is done on @Service/@Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you did wrong the insertion priority in this case, so before saving "announcement" object then you must guarantee that publicProcerument with constraint ID is already existing on the DB:

Maybe you should try re-order below:

```
announcementService.save(announcement);
publicProcurement.setAnnouncement(announcement);
save(publicProcurement);
```

To:

```
publicProcurement.setAnnouncement(announcement);
save(publicProcurement);
announcementService.save(announcement);
```

And remove your annotation insertable = false, updatable = false

If this cannot help you solving the problems then better u show me full your entities.

Comment: It´s not working. Same issue. my entities does not has anything else. Pretty weird!.